# No errors, no problems, nothing showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've spent a solid amount of time on this and I've lost faith in my Heroku abilities.

- I have a rails app
- I've migrated the database
- I've included the rails12_factor gem in production
- I have the Heroku toolbelt
- I've logged in with my credentials via the terminal
- I've created a heroku app with the command "heroku create blahblahblah"
- This gave me my remote
- I've used 'init' 'add .' 'commit' and everything is up to date
- I've deployed with 'git push heroku master'
- My app was deployed successfully without any problems
- It tells me everything is up to date

My production check says everything passes

I can't for the life of me bloody well figure out why, when I go to my app's URL that it only shows the welcome page "Heroku | Welcome to your new app!"

I'd be forever greatful and in your debt to whomever can help me with this.

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.4

Comment: you have to define you root path, ping me on skype if you are not able to solve it my skype id is nitinjain2021

Comment: Have you tried `heroku restart`? Also, got your URL for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of rails you had to delete the index page from the public directory.
I think in rails 4, you need to define a route for root.

so in your config/routes.rb  some thing like :

root to: 'static_pages#home'

Do you have this problem only on Heroku?  what happens on localhost:3000?